# Group by with multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I want to aggregate rows, using different conditions for two columns.

When I do `df.groupby('[a]').agg('count')`, I get the **output 1**

When I do `df.groupby('[a]').agg('mean')`, I get the **output 2**

Is there a way to do an aggregation that show output 1 to the `column[b]` and output 2 to the `column[c]`?

Comment: df.groupby('a').agg({'b':'count','c':'mean'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below should work:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A3'],
                   'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

[image]

```
# Calculate count, mean 
temp1 = df.groupby(['a']).count().reset_index().rename(columns={'value':'count'})
temp2 = df.groupby(['a'])['value'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'value':'mean'})

# Add columns to existing dataframe
df.merge(temp1, on='a', how='inner').merge(temp2, on='a', how='inner')
```

[image]

```
# Add columns to a new dataframe
df2 = temp1.merge(temp2, on='a', how='inner')
df2
```

[image]